# C - How to convert an int to uint8_t?

Tags: c, integer, endianness

I have this struct:

```
struct block{
    uint8_t *tBlock;
}
```

This struct will have 1024 bytes so `tBlock = malloc(1024)`.

I have an integer that I want to write in 4 bytes so tBlock[0] to tBlock[3] in little endian. I have this :

```
uint8_t little[4];

void inttolitend(uint32_t x, uint8_t* lit_int){
   lit_int[3] = (uint8_t)x / (256*256*256);
   lit_int[2] = (uint8_t)(x % (256*256*256)) / (256*256);
   lit_int[1] = (uint8_t)((x % (256*256*256)) % (256*256)) / 256;
   lit_int[0] = (uint8_t)((x % (256*256*256)) % (256*256)) % 256;
}
```

But when I do:

```
int x = 7;
inttolitend(x, little);
```

I got little[0] = 7, little[1] = 0, little[2] = 0 and little[3] = 0 so I totally fail my converter. How could I get 7 in uint8_t in 4 bytes?

Comment: Use brackets? `(uint8_t)x / (256*256*256)` means the same as `((uint8_t)x) / (256*256*256)`, but what you want is `(uint8_t)(x / (256*256*256))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the standard way to do it - nice and concise:

```
void inttolitend(uint32_t x, uint8_t *lit_int) {
    lit_int[0] = (uint8_t)(x >>  0);
    lit_int[1] = (uint8_t)(x >>  8);
    lit_int[2] = (uint8_t)(x >> 16);
    lit_int[3] = (uint8_t)(x >> 24);
}
```

Or using arithmetic similar to your question:

```
void inttolitend(uint32_t x, uint8_t *lit_int) {
    lit_int[0] = (uint8_t)(x % 256);
    lit_int[1] = (uint8_t)(x / 256 % 256);
    lit_int[2] = (uint8_t)(x / 256 / 256 % 256);
    lit_int[3] = (uint8_t)(x / 256 / 256 / 256 % 256);
}
```

---

Addendum:

The reverse conversion - idiomatic:

```
uint32_t litendtoint(uint8_t *lit_int) {
    return (uint32_t)lit_int[0] <<  0
         | (uint32_t)lit_int[1] <<  8
         | (uint32_t)lit_int[2] << 16
         | (uint32_t)lit_int[3] << 24;
}
```

Or using arithmetic similar to your question:

```
uint32_t litendtoint(uint8_t *lit_int) {
    return (uint32_t)lit_int[0]
         + (uint32_t)lit_int[1] * 256
         + (uint32_t)lit_int[2] * 256 * 256
         + (uint32_t)lit_int[3] * 256 * 256 * 256;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D and how could I convert my uint8_t to an integer ? I will write this in a file and I want to get back this information.

Comment: That's great thanks you ! I'm not really good with this language ^^"

Answer (score 3):

```
void inttolitend(uint32_t x, uint8_t* lit_int){

    lit_int[0] = x & 0xff;
    lit_int[1] = (x>> 8) & 0xff;
    lit_int[2] = (x>> 16) & 0xff;
    lit_int[3] = (x>> 24) & 0xff;
}
```

> I got little[0] = 7, little[1] = 0, little[2] = 0 and little[3] = 0

Btw, this *is* Little Endian for 7.

Comment: Thanks and how can I get a int with the uint8_t* ?

Comment: The use of `htonl()` is inappropriate here. The 32-bit number `x` has no endianness to begin with.

Comment: Using `htonl` does _not_ work.  In hex, this is what you get: `01020304 --> 3=04 2=03 1=02 0=01`

Comment: @NayukiMinase - You're right - updated my answer (getting late here.. )

Answer (score 2):

OP uses of `lit_int[3] = (uint8_t)x / (256*256*256);` mistakenly did the cast before the division.

```
void inttolitend(uint32_t x, uint8_t* lit_int){
   lit_int[3] = (uint8_t) (x / 16777216);
   lit_int[2] = (uint8_t) (x / 65536);
   lit_int[1] = (uint8_t) (x / 256);
   lit_int[0] = (uint8_t) x;
}
```

---

Calling `int x = 7; inttolitend(x, little);` is a problem if `int` is not the same as `int32_t`.

`256*256*256` overflow on 16-bit systems.